# "AssertionError: Contract code empty" when testing contract above a particular size. How do I fix it?

Tags: dapp-development, serpent, out-of-gas, testing, contract-deployment

I'm writing a contract for arbitrary-length integer arithmetic, for use in a larger project.

The problem is that once the contract gets above a certain size, the Python ethereum.tester.state().abi_contract() test environment begins giving this stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "se_bigint.py", line 5, in <module>
    bigint = s.abi_contract('bigint.se')
  File "/home/ada/mypy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ethereum/tester.py", line 166, in abi_contract
    assert len(self.block.get_code(address), "Contract code empty")
AssertionError: Contract code empty
```

Here's a pastebin of code that works: http://pastebin.com/1KppMmRx

And here's a pastebin that reproduces the error: http://pastebin.com/qq7mcLeM

Note that the only difference between them is some meaningless busywork added to one of the contract functions. Also note that both contracts successfully compile via "serpent compile bigint.se". I see this both on the PyPI release and on the current github develop branch.

I'd have asked this on the ethereum forum, but I seem to be stuck in account verification over there.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or how to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supplying enough gas for deployment? Before homestead, contracts can deploy without code if you run out of gas during deployment.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. For those of you who read this in the future: try state.abi_contract("script.se",gas=10000000). If that doesn't work, try increasing the gas further.

Comment: A similar option is: ethereum.tester.gas_limit = 3000000  When increasing the gas, it's still good to stay under the block gas limit, otherwise the test contract as is will not be deployable to mainnet.